# Do reactions resolve before or after the action they are reacting to?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, reactions

I'm unsure of how Reactions resolve. The order of priorities seems important both for auras and in particular defences.

If Blink chooses could he teleport outside of the target area to get a guaranteed dodge rather than using his Close attack or does the Reaction occur after the attack has resolved?

- Shield Lass is targeted by an incoming attack, she activates her Reaction Create power to create Full Cover for herself.

Again this relies on the Reaction occurring before the attack however assuming it does this gives her a circumstantial bonus of +5 to parry and +5 to dodge with an extra -5 to the attackers aim check. And if it does not the power is not really all that useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Depends on the ability that gives the Reaction

Some abilities will trigger before the action that triggered them, while others will trigger after the action that triggered them. Each ability should give the specifics on when this happens, if not, the effect happens **immediately** as per *Reaction Extra*:

> When the triggering circumstance occurs, the effect activates
>   automatically, even if it is not the character’s turn.

Before:

- **Interpose**: This reaction happens when an adjacent ally is hit by an attack, and you can replace the target of the attack by your character. Which means that the original target was never hit and your reaction happened before the action that triggered the ability.

> Once per round, when an ally within range of your normal movement is hit by an attack, you can choose to place yourself between the attacker and your ally as a reaction, **making you the target of the attack instead**. The attack hits you rather than your ally, and you suffer the effects normally. (...)

After:

- **Weapon Bind**: After you successfully defend against a close weapon attack, your character can immediately make a disarm attempt against the attacker as a reaction. Here, the reaction happened after the action that triggered the ability.

> If you take the defend action (see Defend in the Action & Adventure chapter) and successfully defend against a close weapon attack, **you can make a disarm attempt against the attacker immediately as a reaction**. The disarm attempt is carried out normally, including the attacker getting the opportunity to disarm you.

- **Energy Aura**: Here, the ability triggers as soon as someone touches your character, and if the ability triggered before the action, the attacker could die before they even actually hit your character.

> You can surround your body with an aura of damaging energy or some similar effect. **Anyone you touch or that touches you must make a Toughness resistance check against your aura’s Damage rank**.

Which means that depending on what *Trigger* was set on the ability, this could happen before or after the action that triggered the ability. If you add a *when I am attacked* trigger to an ability, that happens before you are hit. However, if you add a *when I am hit* trigger to the ability, that happens after you are hit, because a hit happens after an attack roll.

Answer (score 2):

After some searching around I've come to the conclusion that Reactions occur after the Trigger. Cases like I provided above can occur with specific wording however they ought to be a warning flag for abuse of the Reaction power for QMs and can always be vetoed.

Blink Teleport in Power Profiles is the only example where it uses the Trigger 'Immediate Attack'. Because of this I believe that by default reactions occur after the trigger has resolved and that this teleport is a specific exception due to the Trigger being the attack declared rather than the attack occurring.

Comment: *" I've come to the conclusion that Reactions occur after the Trigger"* This is not entirelly correct. For instance, the Reaction to *Interpose* an attack caused by an enemy redirects the target from the intented target to your character. Here, the reaction happened before the trigger, and now the target of the attack is your character, and the original target was never hit.

Comment: I tried to cover this when I was saying that specific wording can change when it occurs. I would have resolved 'Immediate Attack' when the attack is declared but I would resolve just 'Attack' or 'Hit' after the attack check is made.